# Auto generate named range when a cell is filled

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-named-ranges

I'm interested in auto generating named ranges for the sake of easy variable creation for formulas.
I generally use a tab called CONSTANTS while building calculators to help keep the data clean and traceable.  Currently, every time I add a new constant, I have to:

1. create a variable name ex. "Gravity" in A1
2. in the adjacent cell, B2,type the value "9.8"
3. Create named range "Gravity" that points to
   $B$1 containing "9.8"

What I would like to do is auto create a named range when a value is entered in column B and to name that range based on the adjacent cell.

Is this possible with formulas? I have not dealt with scripting yet and if it is scripted will it carry over with template if the user is not aware of how scripts work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question

> Is this possible with formulas? (create a named range)

It's not possible to do this by using formulas but it's possible by using Google Apps Script, more specifically you should use a on edit trigger.

Resources

- [Extending Google Sheets with Apps Script](https://developersg.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [Triggers](https://developersg.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Related

- [Automate range name creation in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100665/88163)